# Cargar Combobox en VB.NET con dos parametros

Tags: vb.net, combobox

Tengo la siguiente sentencia que me carga el CB con los parametros que tiene la clase Finalidad que filta por estados.

```
Private Sub cargarFinalidades()
    Dim dtFinalidades As DataTable

    With ucFinalidad
        .ProcedimientoAlmacenado = "ConsultarFinalidades"
        .NombreCampoCodigo = "idFinalidad"
        .NombreCampoDescr = "Descripcion"
        .ConexionAct = Conexion.Instancia()
        .txtCodigo.Format = TextBoxConFormatoVB.tbFormats.UnsignedNumber
        .txtCodigo.MaxLength = 4
        .llenaCombo(Finalidad.CONSULTA)
     End With
```

Class

```
Namespace GestionMedica.HistoriaClinica
    Public Class Finalidad

        #Region "Tipos de Finalidad"
        Public Const CONSULTA As String = "C"
        Public Const PROCEDIMIENTOS As String = "P"
        #End Region
    End Class

End Namespace
```

lo que necesito que cargue ese CB es tanto la informacion que se encuentra bajo el tipo de finalidad C como en el P sin editar como tal esta clase, como añadir los aparetros de mas a esa consulta

Comment: Haría falta ver el método `llenaCombo`, aunque la pregunta no me queda muy clara todavía.

Comment: Como tal la clase finalidad me lleva a una base de datos que tiene una serie de finalidades con un "Tipo de finalidad " Que consulta la informacion dependiendo si esta entre "C" Y "P" el combobox que me llena el primer codigo solo me trae los parametros consultados bajo la letra "C" y necesito que tambien entren los que tienen la letra "P" dentro de la misma consulta sin tener que cambiar esa clase

Comment: y cual es el problema de cargarlo con las dos cosas? no me queda claro tampoco.